# Ordered Knapsack Problem Correctness/Proof

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, greedy

A thief is given the choice of `n` objects to steal, but only has one knapsack with a capacity of
taking `M` weight. Each object i has weight `w_i`, and profit `p_i`. Suppose he also knows the following:
the order of these items when sorted by increasing weight is the same as their order when sorted
by decreasing value. Give a greedy algorithm to find an optimal solution to this variant of the
knapsack problem. Prove the correctness and running time.

So the greedy algorithm I came up with was to sort the items based off of increasing weight which is also decreasing value. This means that the price per weight is in decreasing order. So the thief can take the highest valued item until the weight `>= M`. The running time would be `O(n log n)` since sorting takes `O(n log n)` and iterating through the list takes `O(n)`. The part I am stuck on is the proof for correctness. Here is my proof so far:

Suppose there is an instance such that the solution stated above (referred to as GA) is not optimal. Let the optimal solution be referred to as OS, and the items taken by OS be sorted in increasing value. Since OS is more optimal than GA, then the profit earned from GA is less than or equal to the profit earned from OS. Since GA takes the item with the highest profit/weight ratio, then the first element, `i`, must be greater than or equal to the first element of OS. Because OS is more optimal, then there must exist a `i` that is greater than or equal to an item j in the set of GA. But because GA and OS are done on the same set, and GA is always taking the item with the highest profit/weight, there cannot be a `i` in OS that is greater than a `j` in GA.

Can anyone help with the proof? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to the solution is valid and the reasoning on the running time is correct. In the sequel, suppose that the input is "de-trivialized" in the sense that every occurring obejct actually fits into the knapsack and that it is impossible to select the entire input.

The sorting of the items that is generated by the sorting is *both*

- decreasing in value
- increasing weight

which makes it a special case of the [general knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). The argumentation for the proof of correctnes is as follows. Let `i'` denote the *breaking index* which is the index of the first item in the sorted sequence which is rejected by the greedy algorithm. For clarity, call the corresponding object the *breaking object*. Note that

```
w_j > w_i' for each j > i'
```

holds, which means that that the greedy algorithm also rejects every object succeeding the breaking object (as it does not fit into the knapsack, just like the breaking object).

In total, the greedy algorithm selects a *prefix* of the sorted sequence; we aim at showing that any optimal solution (which we consider fixed in the sequel) is the same prefix.

Note that the optimal solution, as it it optimal, does not leave space for an additional object.

Aiming at a contradiction, let `k` be the minimal index which occurs in the greedy solution but not in the optimal solution. As it is impossible to select object `k` additionally into the optimal solution, there must (via minimality of `k`) be some item in the optimal solution with an index

```
k' > k
```

which permits an exchange of items in the optimal solution. As

```
w_k < w_k' and p_k > p_k'
```

hold, object `k'` can be replaced by object `k` in the optimal solution, which yields a solution with profit larger than the one of the optimal solution, which is a contradiction to its optimality.

Hence, there is no item in the greedy solution which is missing in the optimal solution, which means that the greedy solution is a subset of the optimal solution. On the other hand, the greedy solution is maximal with respect to inclusion, which means that the optimal solution cannot contain an item which is missing in the greedy solution.

Note that the greedy algorithm als is useful for the general knapsack problem; taking the better one of the greedy solution and an item with maximum profit yields an approximation algorithm with ratio 2.